# Visual Studio 2010 could not start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crash

I have a problem with visual studio 2010 in my PC, when I try to start it I'll see this exception:

> devnev.exe - Application Error
>
> The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occured in the
>   aopplication at location 0x7543d36f

I understand this exception is because of my current user settings, because when I created another account and test visual studio, it works perfectly. So I tried to remove all of current user profile from registry, so I removed entries from these keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\FileMRUList
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectMRUList
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NewProjectDialog\MRUSettingsLocalProjectLocationEntries
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NewProjectDialog\MRUSettingsRecentlyUsedTemplates
```

But still wont works (with similar exception).

Is there any other user settings for VS 2010 in regedit? Is there any other place except regedit for holding user settings?

<sub>PS: my OS is Windows 7.</sub>

Comment: There's also your `vssettings` file. [Reset it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx).

Comment: @ta.speot.is, thanks I'll try it, but do you know exact place of this file?

Comment: For me it's `C:\Users\Todd\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings`

Comment: @ta.speot.is, thank you very much, but still I have problem (but your suggestion was excellent).

Comment: So `Devenv.exe /ResetSettings` didn't help?

Comment: No didn't help, I also replaced related file with other file that I had in another account, but again didn't help.

Comment: Try to remove C:\Users\user-name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010 directory.

Comment: @AlexFarber, thanks for your suggestion, but still I'll get same exception.

Comment: Perhaps you've got a dud add-in installed? There's plenty of user-specific paths documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1326zbk3.aspx).

Comment: It is a low-level CLR exception.  Get .NET 4 healthy again.

Comment: @HansPassant, If it's .net 4 problem, why it's ok for other user accounts?

Comment: How am I supposed to know this?  I never got my machine messed up this badly before.  You are the pioneer here.

Comment: @HansPassant, because I wrote in my question (I tested it with other acounts, and it was ok).